# How can i auto open a ng-dropdown-multiselect in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following definition for a  ng-dropdown-multiselect:

```
               <div id="selectedColumns"
                         ng-dropdown-multiselect="false"
                         extra-settings="ddextraSettings"
                         translation-texts="ddCustomTexts"
                         options="ddOptions"
                         selected-model="ddSelectedModel"
                         checkboxes="true"></div>
                </div>
```

Currently after binding to the drop down via a serie call, I want to drop dow the selection.
I have tried

```
             $scope.selectedColumns.open();
```

but it gives an error that open is not a function

How can i do this ?

Comment: Does this help? `$("#selectedColumns button")[0].click();`

Comment: says its undefined, so i tried $("#selectedColumns button")[0].click;  still didnt open the dropdown

Comment: try it with setTimeout. `setTimeout(function(){$("#selectedColumns button")[0].click();});` Does it work now?

Comment: If jQuery is not added, try `setTimeout(function(){document.querySelectorAll("#selectedColumns button")[0].click();});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If without changing the library, and provided without use of JQuery, then this should do it (using `Javascript`)

```js
setTimeout(function(){document.querySelectorAll("#selectedColumns button")[0].click();});
```